# Loop through all serial addresses to locate hardware

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm new to python and I'm trying to loop through all 255 addresses to locate a specific bit of hardware over RS485. The hardware is attached, and it's address is supposed to be 0x25, but this is not the case, so I need to *find* what its address is.

So far I've got:

```
def Init_Sync_4 ():
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
ser.write([CID,0x17,0x20,0x01,0x14,0x1c,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0$
time.sleep(0.007)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

and

```
ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',baudrate=38400,stopbits=2,timeout=1)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

for i in range(0xff):
    CID = '0x{:02x}'.format(i).encode('ascii')
    print "at address %s" % CID

    Init_Sync_4()
    time.sleep(0.05)

    Init_2()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Here `CID` is the address being built, which `Init_Sync_4()` uses in it's byte array in `ser.write`, but I keep getting the error:

```
at address 0x00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rs485_test_2.py", line 97, in <module>
    Init_4()
  File "rs485_test_2.py", line 40, in Init_4

ser.write([CID,0x17,0x20,0x01,0x14,0x1c,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write
        d = to_bytes(data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 66, in to_bytes
        return bytes(bytearray(seq))
    ValueError: string must be of size 1
```

I'm assuming that it's still being passed as a string, when it needs to be a single byte, but I'm lost at how the conversion would work. I've checked out some SO pages, that specify using `.encode` with or without params, but I'm either using it incorrectly, or it's not quite what I'm after. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ser.write([CID,0x17,0x20,0x01, ...
```

`CID` is going  into a list with a bunch of integers. But itself is a string.

You want to leave CID as an integer.

```
# CID = '0x{:02x}'.format(i).encode('ascii')
CID = i
```